# How PCI-E Lanes are Allocated on Socket AM1 Systems

Tags: pci-express, bus

One of the major limitations of the budget AM1 platform by AMD is that CPUs in this platform only support 4 PCI-E 2.0 lanes for external bus communications (PCI-E slots on the motherboard).

Most motherboards for this line feature a PCI-E 2.0 slot with 16x connectors (only 4x active) and one or more PCI-E 2.0 slots with 1x connectors (1x active).

Obviously, if I plug a GPU into the 16x slot and a RAID card or Wifi into the 1x slot, I'm only going to get 3x PCI-E on the GPU, right? Or is there something I'm not understanding about how that configuration would work?